# C++:: How to concatenate variables using sqlite3 insertquery

Tags: c++, sqlite

Here I'm trying to concatenate variables(int and char) by insertQuery,
     but I'm getting error, My  error is error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 
    'const char   [2]' to binary 'operator+'
     Guys Please Guide me where I'm wrong..

```
     **string insertQuery= "insert into items   (user_id,session_id,user_sessionname,buffer)values("
                        + user + "," + session + ",'" + usrname +   "','" + buff + "')";

         sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;
                   cout << "Creating Insert Statement" << endl;
                   sqlite3_prepare(db, insertQuery.c_str(), insertQuery.size(), &insertStmt, NULL);
                   cout << "Stepping Insert Statement" << endl;
                   if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;**
```

Comment: What are the types of the following variables:  user, session, usrname, and buff. And also, why is there two asterisks before string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming null terminated `char*` or null terminated `char[]`)

Recommend using a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) (`#include <sstream>`) to construct the SQL query:

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << "insert into items "
  << user
  << ','
  << session;

const std::string insertQuery(s.str());
```

It would also be possible by creating temporary `std::string` objects in the concatenation sequence:

```
const std::string insertQuery= 
    std::string("insert into items ... values(")
  + std::string(user)
  + std::string(","); // etc
```

If a `char*` or `char[]` is not null terminated you can inform the `std::string` constructor how long it is:

```
std::string s(buf, 2);
```